# Pico W Read Serial Input

Tags: c, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to read the input sent through the serial monitor but scanf does nothing and i can't figure out how to get getchar to do the same thing.

Here's a piece of code that I've tried to use that does not work on the pico. It does work on my pc.

```
char *readInput() {
    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);

    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        if (i < 1024) {
            str[i++] = ch;
            printf("%c\n", ch); // For debugging. Returns the correct character.
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", str); // For debugging. Returns nothing.
    str[i] = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

It looks like it just tries to read until it gets to the 1024th character.

Also I've read somewhere that scanf doesn't work on the Pico but some people say it works so i don't even know anymore.

Comment: You must move `str[i] = '\0';` above the line that must have a string, and you must stop the loop after `1023` characters to leave room for it. Aside: `char ch;` should be `int ch;` because `getchar()` *doesn't* get a `char`.

Comment: I fixed it but it does not make a difference on neither pc and the pico.

Comment: Show how you are using `scanf`. In this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberrypipico/comments/wgvyq8/issue_with_serial_input/) they claim that "scanf doesn't work" but nobody pointed out that `scanf("%i", userInput);` should be `scanf("%i", &userInput);`. Also, show the *actual data* that you are receiving. if the first byte is `0` you'll have the empty string.

Comment: `getchar` uses the `stdin` stream. In a more standard environment (e.g. `linux/posix` application), `stdin` is tied to the input terminal/console. What environment are you using on the pico (linux, FreeRTOS, bare metal)? Are you sure that the UART is configured properly and that `stdin` is hooked up to it? Have you double checked the UART cable that connects to a terminal program (e.g. kermit, putty, etc.)? And, ensured that the configuration (baud rate, etc.) and the RTS/CTS on both sides is set correctly?

Comment: Avoid `mailloc()` on microcontrollers. While it is provided for, the pool of available memory you have to draw from is tiny. More so on the pico_w where there is an additional 220K of flash used by the iwlp networking library. Further, if you are going to use `mailloc()` you need to provide compiler options specifying how much dynamic memory to make available. Bottom like, except for exceptional circumstances, stick with arrays with automatic storage duration on the pico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serial monitor I was using was just broken and it didn't display/send things correctly. Changing it to arduino's one fixed the problem and I can use scanf now.

Answer (score 4):

**`malloc()`'s result is discarded:**

```
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
```

`malloc()` returns a `NULL` pointer to indicate failure, which it can and does. Its return value should always be checked. If it returns `NULL`, subsequent operations would be dereferencing and writing to a `NULL` pointer.

Aside: `sizeof (char)` is defined to be 1, so you can leave that out.

```
char *str = malloc(1024);
/* Add */
if (!str) {
   /* malloc() failed to allocate memory.
    * Handle error here.
    */
}
```

---

**Off-by-one error:**

```
if (i < 1024)
```

doesn't leave room for the null-byte.

---

**`getchar()` returns an `int`:**

```
char ch;

while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
```

> If the integer value returned by getchar() is stored into a
> variable of type char and then compared against the integer
> constant EOF, the comparison may never succeed, because sign-
> extension of a variable of type char on widening to integer is
> implementation-defined.

---

**Undefined behaviour:**

```
printf("%s\n", str); // For debugging. Returns nothing.
```

The `%s` format specifier expects a string. `str` is not a string. The call to `printf()` would invoke undefined behaviour.

Move

```
str[i] = '\0';
```

before the call to `printf()`.

---

**Writing to out of bounds memory:**

```
    str[i] = '\0';
```

The value of `i` is 1024 when the `while` loop exits. You only allocated memory for 1023 characters.

---

**Minor:**

```
char *readInput()
```

indicates that `readInput` takes an unspecified number and type of arguments.

```
char *readInput (void)
```

doesn't.

Comment: it is tiny micro and malloc should not be used at all.  **`While it's unlikely for malloc() to fail these days`** it is very likely malloc to fail in this target.

Comment: @0___________ Mm..I reformulated that part.